# Where clause on count column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables pdc and class

```
select roll_no as roll,sum(pdc.amount) as amount,count(amount) as given,
       stu_profile.name,f_name,scholarship,class_id,batch_id,statuss 
from stu_profile left join 
     pdc 
     on pdc.roll=stu_profile.roll_no 
where 1 and class_id!='' and given=0 
group by roll
```

I want a condition on count (amount) column

Comment: What you are trying to achieve ??

Comment: i want all data which given=0 from query

Comment: you wan't `everything` that is not in that query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `having` clause instead

```
 . . .
having count(amount) = 0;
```

Comment: where i have add this

Answer (score 0):

Then answer to your question is the `having` clause.  But, your query is malformed and would not work in most databases, including the more recent versions of MySQL.

The solution is simple:  In an aggregation query, the only columns in the  `SELECT` should be the `GROUP BY` keys or arguments to aggregation functions.

Let me assume that you want:

```
select p.roll_no as roll, sum(pdc.amount) as amount,
       count(pdc.amount) as given,
       p.name, p.f_name, p.scholarship, p.class_id, p.batch_id, p.statuss
from stu_profile p left join 
     pdc 
     on pdc.roll = p.roll_no 
where 1 and class_id <> '' 
group by roll, p.name, p.f_name, p.scholarship, p.class_id, p.batch_id, p.statuss
```

You can then just add something like:

```
having given = 0
```

Comment: its giving me Unknown column 'given' in 'where clause'

Comment: @vivekmodi . . . Oh, that is the error.  You just move that to a `having` clause.